# Error with memcache memcached php 7.4

Tags: php, memcached, memcache

The Server have this Error:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'memcached.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/memcached.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/memcached.so: undefined symbol: zend_wrong_parameter_error), /usr/lib/php/20190902/memcached.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/memcached.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) at Unknown#0
```

but the Status is:

```
● memcached.service - memcached daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-12-28 10:50:49 CET; 2min 5s ago
       Docs: man:memcached(1)
   Main PID: 235657 (memcached)
      Tasks: 10 (limit: 11879)
     Memory: 2.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/memcached.service
             └─235657 /usr/bin/memcached -m 2560 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 0.0.0.0 -P /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid

Dez 28 10:50:49 nextcloudserver systemd[1]: memcached.service: Succeeded.
Dez 28 10:50:49 nextcloudserver systemd-memcached-wrapper[118166]: Signal handled: Terminated.
Dez 28 10:50:49 nextcloudserver systemd[1]: Stopped memcached daemon.
Dez 28 10:50:49 nextcloudserver systemd[1]: Started memcached daemon.
```

Comment: i have install

     apt install php7.4-memcached   php7.4-igbinary

and now. Module 'memcached' already loaded at Unknown#0

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP installation has an incompatible version of the `memcached` PHP module.

You need to make sure that main PHP and its PHP memcache module are installed from the same source.

`memcached` service is the actual daemon that stores the data. PHP `memcached` module is the adapter that facilitates connections to the `memcached` daemon.